# How to get the processes running the sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am getting the deadlock problem in our database on a table .

I am getting the following error message :

```
3/13/2015 11:37:35 AM
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Transaction (Process ID 143) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
at clsdb.clsDB.execcmd(String strsql)
at clspllog.Clspllog.RunXPSPushliveResponse(String pushtype, String journalname, String strvol, String strissue, String articleid, String PushLiveResponseTime, Int32 plstatus, String plstatusmsg, String strerrmsg)
```

There is one method named `RunXPSPushliveResponse` using the table `articleschedule` . it is trying to update this table , but it got the above error message.

I am not able to know which is another process which is using this table. 
thus not able to take any action.

Is there some way so I got the processes using this table or any other way . Totally blank with this issue. Any hint will be much appreciated. I am fresher, so don't have much ideas to rectify this.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following queries for getting the info mentioned in the log.

[SQL Server:Check for all running process and Kill ?](https://dwhanalytics.wordpress.com/2011/03/14/sql-servercheck-for-all-running-process-and-kill/)

You can also use Activity Monitor which can help you with all the activities in the server

[Activity Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc879320%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)